# macOS WKWebView background transparency

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

If someone has experience with `WKWebView`, please share how to make the background of the view transparent. The `WebView` object has such option via `var drawsBackground: Bool { get set }` but it is missing for the `WKWebView` class. I searched the net and .. found nothing. Before time it was possible to do so via `opaque` property, but not anymore. There is a getter `isOpaque` ... and that's it. I don't want to do it via CSS and already tried everything else, like:

> webview.wantsLayer = true
>
> webview.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor

If someone can help ...

I. Nikolov

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent background WKWebView (NSView)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211561/transparent-background-wkwebview-nsview)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I've tried everything written in there - it's not working anymore. And I have described this in the question.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you think it can be helpful to other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work for both macOS 10.11 and macOS 10.12:

```
if NSAppKitVersion.current.rawValue > 1500 {
    webView.setValue(false, forKey: "drawsBackground")
}
else {
    webView.setValue(true, forKey: "drawsTransparentBackground")
}
```

**Remark**: this has been passed by App Store review.

Comment: Let me try it. Would it pass the review? Any experience with this?

Comment: OK. It is working. I'm not sure that this will pass the review, but I'll give it a try and will mark your answer as correct. Thank you for the help ;-)

Comment: I have submitted a Feedback Assistant report about this: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/81 If you also want to see this being officially supported, please duplicate this report.

Comment: As of ~iOS14 `drawsTransparentBackground` is deprecated and should not be used anymore (although there is no real alternative)

Answer (score 0):

Your web page should have transparent background as well.

Comment: If I call `webview.setValue(true, forKey: "drawsTransparentBackground")` it becomes transparent, but in the console there is a message : `[WKWebView _setDrawsTransparentBackground:] is deprecated and should not be used.`. The problem is not in the web page not being transparent.

Comment: @IvayloNikolov: this was the correct method in macOS 10.11. The deprecation in macOS 10.12 should be the real issue as part of your question.

Comment: Yes - exactly. You are correct. Still can't find the answer.